# how to get decomposition result of dwt3

Tags: matlab

Function **dwt3** is from Wavelet Toolbox to perform Single-level discrete 3-D wavelet transform.I tested as below.I have two questions, **one**: how to get the decomposition mat results in 8 different high and low frequency level, **two**:how to keep the same dimensions with input mat, i.e., the  decomposition mat dim is still 4*4*4 as same as the input 3D array.

```
X = reshape(1:64,4,4,4)
wt = dwt3(X,'coif1')

wt = 

sizeINI: [4 4 4]
filters: [1x1 struct]
   mode: 'sym'
    dec: {2x2x2 cell}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get decomposition values by appending .dec{level}. .i.e.

```
X = reshape(1:64,4,4,4);

wt = dwt3(X,'coif1');

wt.dec{1}

wt.dec{2}
```

Comment: thank you. Exactly from  dec: {2x2x2} there are 8 filter results, and I wonder what the relationship is between the decompostion result and the input data. If the input data is a batch of images, how to get the filtered image?

Comment: Another strange thing. If input 4*4*4, the result decompostion still 4*4*4, but why input 512*512*40, result changed to 258*258*22?

Comment: The answer of both of your queries lies in architecture of wavelet transform. dwt3 is 1 level 3D decomposition of your input 3D matrix. Each level of wavelet decomposition consists of 2 steps .i.e. apply low-pass and high-pass filter (which will divide frequency band in half) and down conversion by a factor of 2. So after passing your image from dwt3, you will have two images wt.dec{1} and wt.dec{2}. One will contain HF components and the other will contain LF components of mother image.

Comment: As filteration is actually convolution and we have 'coif1' filter which has a length of 5. So, in case of 512x512x40 after convolution we will have a length (512+5-1) x (512+5-1) x (40+5-1) = 516x516x44. After down-conversion by 2, we will have a length 258x258x22. Yet in case of length 4, we will have (4+5-1)x(4+5-1)x(4+5-1)=8x8x8. After down-conversion, it will become 4x4x4.